# applying hover effect to 2 divs

Tags: css, html, mouseover, swap

Hi I'm tearing my hair out right now, I found this script online which enables me to use my own google+ button instead of their ugly one

```
html:        
<div class="googleplus">  
    <div class="googlehider">  
        <g:plusone annotation="none"></g:plusone>  

        <!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
          window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};  

          (function() {  
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;  
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';  
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);  
          })();  
        </script>  
    </div>  
    <img src="images/googleplus.png" class="mygoogle" />  
</div>  

css:
.googleplus {  
position:relative;  
/* - use this to position your share icon on your page -  */  
}  
.googlehider {  
opacity:0;  
height:30px;  
width:30px;  
position:absolute;  
top:0;  
left:0;  
z-index:3;  
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";  
filter:alpha(opacity=0);  
}  
.mygoogle {  
position:absolute;  
top:0;  
left:0;  
z-index:2;  
margin-left:6px;  
}
```

This is fine if you have a static image but mine has a mouseover effect so I have tried to implement the following from this example http://api.jquery.com/hover/ to enable multiple hover effects in multiple divs which isn't working - what am I doing wrong? I mention facebook below as I'm trying to implement on google+ and facebook buttons

```
<script>
$('div.facebookhider').hover(
function () {
$('div.myfacebook').addClass(".facebookhover"); 
}, 
function () {
$('div.myfacebook').removeClass(".facebookhover"); 
}
);
</script>

<div class="facebookshare">
<!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="facebookhider">  
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="mywebsite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="myfacebook"><li class="facebook"><a>Facebook</a></li></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any elements with an `id` of `facebookhider` or `myfacebook`. Try this instead:

```
<script>
$(".facebookhider").hover(
function () {
$('.myfacebook').addClass("facebookhover"); 
}, 
function () {
$('.myfacebook').removeClass("facebookhover"); 
}
);
</script>
```

### Or just use CSS

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ue/1/)

```css
.social-links .facebookshare .facebookhider:hover + div li a {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.social-links .googleplus .googlehider:hover + li a {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1357902, well, are you having an issue with the Facebook or Google+ button? You mention Google+, but the example you provided that isn't working refers to Facebook. That may be part of the issue.

Comment: correct! I had forgot to say that I'm trying to implement on both the google+ and facebook button if it helps you can look here livefootballstreams.tv/newsite (I'm currently only testing on the facebook button)

Comment: JavaScript listener is probably being overridden. How about just use plain old CSS? See my updated answer :)

Comment: Brilliant the CSS worked - why's it always the simple answer!! - Thanks again

Comment: Update - works perfectly in chrome and firefox in ie 9 I have to hover slightly below the link for it to work - any idea why - i've updated the code here for you to try livefootballstreams.tv/newsite

Comment: @user1357902, that would be because that's where `.facebookhider` or `.googlehider` is positioned in IE9. If you were able to capture the hover with JavaScript, you'd have to watch for a hover on `.googlehider > div`, and trigger the effect on the `li` then. Or, when browsers add support for [nesting](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-hierarchies/) and [selecting the subject of the selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject), you'll be able to do `.social-links .googleplus ~.googlehider > div:hover { & + li a {/* styles here */}}`, but this is still a few years off (and may change).